# Sequence Generator keeps starting with a new value each time it is compiled

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have used

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="q_seq", sequenceName="q_id")

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="q_seq")
```

in my entity class above ID but each time I compile the program the id value isnt continued from the previous value but instead the start value changes.

[image: This is how my id column looks like in my database]

Please Help, Thank you!

Comment: Did you delete entitities in between or have failed creations? Note that the sequence is part of the DB so recompiling or restarting your application should not change the sequence and thus values keep growing.

Comment: @Thomas No, I have not deleted any entities and no failed creations. But each time I run it on local host and recompile it, the starting value changes and while the same instance of the server is running then the values get incremented but If I restart it then the starting value differs

Answer (score 0):

It is expected, It is due to SequenceGenerator internally using HiLo algortihm. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/SequenceHiLoGenerator.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hi/Lo_algorithm

You should only assume it will be increasing and unique by default.

However if you modify the sequence generator annotation with
allocationSize = 1, initialValue= 1
then it should behave the way you expect But it comes with performance cost

Comment: You might want to link to a newer version of hibernate and directly to where said optimizations are described.

Comment: Hi Thomas, The documentation states "id generator using the hilo algorithm" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hi/Lo_algorithm which is the optimization I was mentioning.  "The basic idea is that you have two numbers to make up a primary key- a "high" number and a "low" number. A client can basically increment the "high" sequence, knowing that it can then safely generate keys from the entire range of the previous "high" value with the variety of "low" values."

Comment: Yeah, I know the hilo algorithm but others might not. Instead of "optimizations" you could directly point that out. What still remains is the issue with your link pointing to Hibernate 3 which should be in even less use every day.